# Smooth bivariate functions identifiable under permutations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, permutations, smoothness, random-permutations

Consider a "smooth" $f : [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ and let $\pi : [n] \to [n]$ be a permutation of $[n] =\{1,\dots,n\}$. Let us define
$$
  A^{f,\pi} := \Big( f\Big(\frac{\pi(i)}{n},\frac{\pi(j)}{n}\Big) \Big)_{i,j \in [n]} 
$$
Note that $A^{f,\pi}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. The general question is this: can we identify $f$ (and perhaps $\pi$), based solely on the the observation of $A^{f,\pi}$, or rather to what degree can we do this identification?

A bit more precisely: is the map $f \mapsto A^{f,\pi}$ injective over a class of smooth functions (that perhaps excludes constants) for all permutations $\pi$. Alternatively, is the given map injective over some class of smooth functions for a random permutation $\pi$, with high probability?

EDIT: As was pointed out, let us assume $f$ to be symmetric. In other words, it is a graphon in the language used in graph limit theory and exchangeable random arrays.

Comment: For $f$ symmetric and otherwise nice you may want to consider it as a graphon, cf. https://people.math.osu.edu/glasscock.4/graphons.pdf

Comment: @SteveHuntsman, Of course I do! That is where it came from. Thanks for realizing it. What is missing in the literature though is precisely what I asked. As a graphon, you only care about the equivalence class under permutations. In other words, you identify symmetric bivariate functions that can be mapped to each other by measure-preserving transformations. My question is whether imposing enough smoothness assumptions allows one to identify a particular member of that equivalence class.